# Is doing others projects haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam Aalaykom brothers,

I have a question for all of you which I can’t seem to get my head around. I try my best not to harm others in the sight of Allah and whenever I get a new job which I am skeptical about I make dua to Allah to block it for me if it’ll harm anyone and subhan Allah it gets cut out of nowhere alHamdulIAllah.

I have been doing assignments and projects for university students for the past three years in exchange for money and all was well. Then my friend told me that it’s haram and it should stop. Here was his argument:
That I am harming their integrity and blocking their learning by giving them this favor.

However my counter argument: isn’t it the same as doing freelance work for let’s say a company who wants a project. It is not willing to get an employee however they get an employee online to do their task for a sum of money which could be cheaper. A normal employee would be expected to learn from his work and projects.

Comment: I don't see any problem. We are fully allowed to work for science and for money, if we are not working against the rulings of Isalm in a particular way.